# php switch only using the default code block

Tags: php

I have a php switch statement and  for some reason php switch is only executing the default code in the default block but not in the case block, i check if my variable is isset  first, then use switch to select data from my DB here is the code

```
$sel = 1;
    $sql = "(select * from insurance_companies WHERE id='$eop' LIMIT $sel)";
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){ 
    $cID = $row['id'];  
    $cname = $row['name'];          
    }
 if  (isset($cname)) {
                    switch ($cname) {
                        case 'CASH':
                            $query= "SELECT test FROM cash_procedures WHERE test LIKE '%$did%'";
                 $result= $con->query($query);
 break;

                        default:
                              $query= "SELECT test FROM procedures WHERE test LIKE '%$did%'";
                 $result= $con->query($query);

}
    }
```

i want to execute the case code if my $cname variable matches it, but instead it returns  results from the table in the default code block. i looked at different posts here [PHP switch not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966423/php-switch-not-working-as-expected) , here [PHP switch "||" not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569302/php-switch-not-working-properly) and here [PHP switch case default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904108/php-switch-case-default)

but they do not address my issue

Comment: No, `echo $cname;` before the switch. Or maybe `var_dump($cname);`

Comment: i get this string(4) "CASH" 

but it does not echo anything from the DB

Comment: and with echo i get CASH which means yes indeed it should be working but for some reason its not

Comment: $cname is only ever going to be whatever the last row of the database has it as. What is the value of $cname after the foreach loop, but before the switch statement?

Comment: before the foreach loop $cname does not exist

Answer (score -1):

It is because `$cname` is something different then `CASH`. Maybe it's case insensitive? run strtolower on $cname:

```
switch(strtolower($cname)) {
  case 'cash':
    echo 'got $$';
    break;
}
```

Comment: this does not change anything